# Como usar Web Authentication en Angular

Tags: angular, api

Estoy tratando de implementar un login usando solo Angular, Google Chrome fingerprint feature (que me permite acceder al recurso del fingerprint usando solo el Google Chrome) y la API de https://webauthn.me/introduction que supuestamente me permite registrar y logearme mediante un código en Javascript, este codigo que me brindan no se donde hacerlo funcionar si estoy usando Angular con Typescript.

Este es el código que me da la API y dice permitirme registrar nuevas credenciales:

```
navigator.credentials
  .create({
    publicKey: {
      // random, cryptographically secure, at least 16 bytes
      challenge: base64url.decode("<%= challenge %>"),
      // relying party
      rp: {
        name: "Awesome Corp" // sample relying party
      },
      user: {
        id: base64url.decode("<%= id %>"),
        name: "<%= name %>",
        displayName: "<%= displayName %>"
      },
      authenticatorSelection: { userVerification: "preferred" },
      attestation: "direct",
      pubKeyCredParams: [
        {
          type: "public-key",
          alg: -7 // "ES256" IANA COSE Algorithms registry
        }
      ]
    }
  })
  .then(res => {
    var json = publicKeyCredentialToJSON(res);
    // Send data to relying party's servers
    post("/webauthn/register", {
      state: "<%= state %>",
      provider: "<%= provider %>",
      res: JSON.stringify(json)
    });
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

El código también lo he usado en mi Backend de NodeJS pero no me reconoce el objeto navigator.
Alguien ha usado esta API antes?

Mi meta es poder logearme con el fingerprint así tal y como el DEMO de https://webauthn.me/

Answer (score 1):

navigator es un metodo del objeto window,
deberia poner:

```
window.navigator.create({
    })
```